# Approximating a function using one hidden neural networks

Tags: neural-networks, matlab

I have implemented a neural network that has one hidden layer to approximate the following function:
[image]

by trying different numbers of nodes (ranging from 1 to 20). Using 6 nodes in the hidden layer had the best results (lowest mse). I want to know if there is any relationship between the number of hidden layers and the inflection points in the function.

Comment: It might be interesting for you to plot each neuron s contribution to the output

Comment: It seems that each neuron tries to approximate a portion of the sinusoidal function. And indeed, there is a relationship between the number of hidden layers and the inflection points in the function.